Why do messages stop sending from other worker instances when a new one is started in a MassTransit + Quartz setup?
Problem:
I have a .NET worker application using MassTransit with the Quartz scheduler to send recurring heartbeat messages to an API. I am running two separate instances of the worker, each with a unique InstanceId. However, when I start a new worker instance, the other instance stops sending messages.
Code Implementation:

ScheduleHeartbeatWorker - This class is responsible for scheduling recurring heartbeat sends:
using MassTransit;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using QueryHub.Worker.Consumers.SendHeartbeat;
using QueryHub.Worker.Options;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QueryHub.Worker;

internal class ScheduleHeartbeatWorker(IBus bus,
    ILogger<ScheduleHeartbeatWorker> logger,
    IOptionsMonitor<WorkerOptions> workerOptions,
    IOptionsMonitor<SendHeartbeatOptions> heartbeatOptions) :
    IHostedService
{
    private readonly string _quartQueueName = "queue:quartz";

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Starting the heartbeat scheduling worker");

        ISendEndpoint schedulerEndpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri(_quartQueueName));

        await schedulerEndpoint.ScheduleRecurringSend(
            new Uri($"queue:{heartbeatOptions.CurrentValue.QueueName}-{workerOptions.CurrentValue.InstanceId}"),
            new SendHeartbeatSchedule(),
            new TriggerSendHeartbeatMessage(),
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Stopping the heartbeat scheduling worker");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


Schedule class - This schedule the recurring message to be sent every minute.
public sealed class SendHeartbeatSchedule : DefaultRecurringSchedule
{
    public SendHeartbeatSchedule()
    {
        CronExpression = "0 * * * * ?"; // Every minute
    }
}


Consumer - Consumer that sends the heartbeat
public sealed class SendHeartbeatConsumer : IConsumer<TriggerSendHeartbeatMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<SendHeartbeatConsumer> _logger;
    private readonly IQueryHubService _queryHubService;

    public SendHeartbeatConsumer(
        IQueryHubService queryHubService,
        ILogger<SendHeartbeatConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _queryHubService = queryHubService;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TriggerSendHeartbeatMessage> context)
    {
        Result heartbeatResult = await _queryHubService.SendHeartbeat();

        if (!heartbeatResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            throw new Exception(heartbeatResult.Errors.First().Description);
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("Heartbeat sent.");
    }
}


Configuration - Adding MassTransit and Quartz configuration:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

        x.AddConsumer<SendHeartbeatConsumer>();

        x.AddConsumer<ExecuteQueryConsumer, ExecuteQueryConsumerDefinition>()
            .Endpoint(e =>
            {
                WorkerOptions workerOptions = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(WorkerOptions.Key)
                                    .Get<WorkerOptions>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Worker configuration is required");

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workerOptions.InstanceId))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Worker:InstanceId is required");
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workerOptions.QueueName))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Worker:QueueName is required");
                }

                e.Name = workerOptions.QueueName;

                e.Temporary = false;

                e.InstanceId = workerOptions.InstanceId;

                e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
            });

        ConfigureRabbitMqTransport(hostContext, x);

        SendHeartbeatOptions sendHeartbeatOptions = hostContext.Configuration
            .GetSection(SendHeartbeatOptions.Key)
            .Get<SendHeartbeatOptions>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("send heartbeat options are not configured");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sendHeartbeatOptions.QueueName))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("send heartbeat queue name is not configured");
        }

        x.AddPublishMessageScheduler();

        x.AddQuartzConsumers();

        x.Configure<MassTransitHostOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.WaitUntilStarted = true;
        });

        x.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
        {
            options.StartDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
        });

        x.AddHostedService<ScheduleHeartbeatWorker>();
    });

    services.AddQuartz(q =>
    {
        QuartzConfigurationOptions quartzConfiguration = hostContext.Configuration
            .GetSection(QuartzConfigurationOptions.Key)
            .Get<QuartzConfigurationOptions>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Quartz is not configured");

        q.SchedulerName = quartzConfiguration.InstanceName;
        q.SchedulerId = quartzConfiguration.SchedulerId;

        q.UseInMemoryStore();

        q.UseDefaultThreadPool(tp =>
        {
            // Number of concurrent tasks that can be dispatched to CLR thread pool
            tp.MaxConcurrency = 1;
        });
    });
}

private static void ConfigureRabbitMqTransport(HostBuilderContext hostContext, IBusRegistrationConfigurator x)
{
    IConfigurationSection rabbitMqConfig = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMq");

    string? rabbitMqHost = rabbitMqConfig["Host"];
    string? rabbitMqVirtualHost = rabbitMqConfig["VirtualHost"] ?? "/";
    string? rabbitMqUsername = rabbitMqConfig["Username"];
    string? rabbitMqPassword = rabbitMqConfig["Password"];

    SendHeartbeatOptions sendHeartbeatOptions = hostContext.Configuration
        .GetSection(SendHeartbeatOptions.Key)
        .Get<SendHeartbeatOptions>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("send heartbeat options are not configured");

    WorkerOptions workerOptions = hostContext.Configuration
        .GetSection(WorkerOptions.Key)
        .Get<WorkerOptions>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(rabbitMqHost, rabbitMqVirtualHost, h =>
        {
            h.Username(rabbitMqUsername);
            h.Password(rabbitMqPassword);
        });

        cfg.UsePublishMessageScheduler();

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName: $"{sendHeartbeatOptions.QueueName}-{workerOptions.InstanceId}", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<SendHeartbeatConsumer>(context);
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
}



Issue:
When I start a new worker instance, messages from the previous instance stop being sent, and only the new worker instance continues sending messages. This happens even though both worker instances should be running independently and should not affect each other.
The behavior seems to be tied to the Quartz and MassTransit configuration, where the scheduling might be shared or interfering between the two worker instances. I am trying to understand why this happens and how to ensure that each worker instance can continue sending messages independently when new instances are started.
What I've tried:

Ensured that each worker instance has a unique InstanceId and queue name.
I can't use the any other queue name instead of quartz.
Looked into potential issues with MassTransit and Quartz configurations but couldn't find the root cause.

What I'm looking for:

An explanation of why starting a new worker instance would stop the messages of other worker instances.
A solution to ensure that each worker instance can send heartbeat messages independently without interfering with others.
Don't want to use a persistent store as I don't need to maintain a state. Just want workers are online they send a heartbeat.


Just a comment, Stack Overflow is not an official support channel, so do not expect the author or maintainers to respond to your question. If you need product support, contact support.
